Cryptography not Install properly
Facing the issue of cryptography. I have already installed the version of cryptography==3.4.8 and pyopenssl==21.0.0 but the issue raised about
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 53, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.x509 import _Certificate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.x509'

No idea how to resolve. python version 3.10

The versions of the packages you are using cryptography 3.4.8 and pyOpenSSL 21.0.0 supports Python 3.6 - 3.9.
There are newer versions that supports your python version (3.10). You might want to upgrade those packages to the stable release or downgrade to a supported python version for the older releases.
This should fix your errors but if it persists, you can have a look at the issues raised on GitHub.
